# How to import Apple Mail archive files in Outlook 2013?

Tags: mail.app, windows, ms-office

I need to import Apple Mail archived files in Outlook 2013 on Windows, but every time I open the import wizard and reach the file selection step, I cannot select the archived file. It doesn't even show in the dialog box.

I don't know what the issue is. Is it the file size issue as the archive file is large (about 7 GB) or there is any other fault?

Comment: Let's see if somebody here can offer some help here. If not we can help you to find a better place to ask the question (e.g. on a site more focused on Windows).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If both system are using the IMAP mail provider all you have to do is setup the connection to the mail server and all the emails and folders will be copied down to the windows computer. That is what IMAP is for. The mail stays on the server, and can be store on the local computer also, and when you connect to the server with another device, computer, phone or pad, all the mail with folders gets copied to the other device.

But I think some of your mail was gotten using POP so it is not longer on the server.

Or you have emails in local folder only and they would be on the server. But you can create folder on the server in one mail program, or on the mail web interface and then copy those emails into those folder on the server byt copying them in one of the email programs. Then when you log on with the other device all of them will be downloaded to the other device.

Other alternative:-
You can find various solutions on having a [google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=apple%20mail%20to%20outlook%20conversion&btnK=&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1v) search for your problem.
Or you can have a look at the following link: [Apple mail to Outlook Windows](http://applemailtopst.com)

Answer (score 1):

Apple mail archive are in **.mbox** format which is not a supported Outlook format in windows. You cannot import this file, that's why.

You might want to look for a **.mbox to .pst converter**.

To help you out this might help you:
[Trial MBOX Converter](http://corrupt-mbox-to-pst.weebly.com/)